# How to call a cucumberTestRunner?

Tags: java, groovy, junit, cucumber, cucumber-junit

How do I call my cucumberTestRunner from another class (cucumberTestMaster) and get it to run? Currently, it just seems to skip the tests. Below is what I have tried. I am limited by JUnit 4.8 for project reasons, and both files are written in Groovy.

```
//cucumberTestMaster
package cucumber

import cucumber.testRunners.CucumberTestRunner
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
import org.junit.runner.Result

class CucumberTestMaster {
    
        try {
            Class runner = CucumberTestRunner as Class
            Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(runner.class)
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            println(e)
        }
    

   
}
```

---

```
//cucumberTestRunner

package cucumber.testRunners

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/main/groovy/cucumber/features/addDeal/",
        glue = "cucumber.stepDefinitions",
        publish = false,
        monochrome = true,
        tags = "@Daily",
        plugin = ["pretty", "junit:target/JUNITReports/report.xml", "html:target/HTMLReports/report.html",
                "json:target/JSONReports/report.json"]
)
class CucumberTestRunner {
}
```

---

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I don't see any thing wrong. But your example isn't very minimal. For example you've got a `tags = "@Daily"` filter in place that may not behave as expected. So you may want to simplify some more. Perhaps even with a regular JUnit 4 test and see if that works.

Comment: Btw, cucumber has a main class on `io.cucumber.core.main.Main`. Why bother with JUnit 4 right now?

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje, I have tried to implement the 'cucumber.api.cli.Main' but I get the following error: "No backends were found. Please make sure you have a backend module on your CLASSPATH." Does this mean I am missing a dependency?

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje  The link to my code can be found: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73399858/19625157?sem=2