# Trying to implement cucumber.api.cli.Main.main()

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit, cucumber-serenity

I have tried to implement the 'cucumber.api.cli.Main' but I get the following error: "No backends were found. Please make sure you have a backend module on your CLASSPATH." Does this mean I am missing a dependency? My Gradle and java code is below.

---

java code

```
package cucumber;

import cucumber.api.cli.Main;

import java.io.PrintStream;

public class CucumberRunEngine {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
            Main.main(
                    new String[]{
                            "CLASSPATH:src.main.groovy.cucumber.features.addDeal",
                            //"-t", "@Daily",
                            "-g", "cucumber.stepDefinitions",
                            "-p", "pretty",
                            "-p", "html:target/HTMLReports/report.html",
                            "-p", "junit:target/JUNITReports/report.xml",
                            "-p", "json:target/JSONReports/report.json",
                            "-m"
                    }
            );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            PrintStream printer =System.out;
            printer.println(e);
            for (int element=0;element<e.getStackTrace().length;element++) {
                printer.println(e.getStackTrace()[element]);
            }
       }
    }
}
```

---

Gradle code

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'application'
    id "se.thinkcode.cucumber-runner" version "0.0.8"
}

dependencies {
    //Standard
    api "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:${groovyVersion}"
    api "com.reuters:corejavalib:${coreJavaLibVersion}"
    api "com.oracle:ojdbc7:${ojdbc7Version}"

    implementation "commons-io:commons-io:${commonsIoVersion}"
    implementation "commons-lang:commons-lang:${commonLangVersion}"

    //JUnit
    implementation "junit:junit:${jUnitVersion}"
//    implementation("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite")
    compileOnly "org.testng:testng:${testNGVersion}"

    //Cucumber
    compileOnly "io.cucumber:cucumber-java:${cucumberVersion}"
    compileOnly "io.cucumber:cucumber-java8:${cucumberVersion}"
    compileOnly "io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:${cucumberVersion}"
    compileOnly "io.cucumber:cucumber-groovy:${cucumberGroovyVersion}"
    compileOnly "io.cucumber:cucumber-gherkin:${cucumberVersion}"
    compileOnly "io.cucumber:cucumber-jvm-groovy:${cucumberGroovyVersion}"
    compileOnly "io.cucumber:cucumber-junit-platform-engine:${cucumberVersion}"
    implementation "io.cucumber:cucumber-core:${cucumberVersion}"


}
application{
    mainClass="cucumber.CucumberRunEngine"
}

repositories {
}
```

---

Gradle.properties

```
# versions of dependencies used in this project defined here
groovyVersion=2.5.7

commonCliVersion=1.3.1
commonsIoVersion=2.6
commonLangVersion=2.6

#JUnit
jUnitVersion=4.8
testNGVersion=7.4.0
jUnitPlatformSuiteVersion=1.9.0

#Cucumber
cucumberVersion=7.4.0
cucumberGroovyVersion=6.10.4

ojdbc7Version=12.1.0.2
coreJavaLibVersion=3.5.21.9
```

---

Thank you for any help in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Your project setup is a bit peculiar. There are too many parts that simply don't belong. For example as a result of using `compileOnly` you're not including the code you need at runtime. And so Cucumber complains it can't find `cucumber-java` (a backend).

Now you may have already noticed this and scoped `cucumber-core` to `implementation` for this reason. But this suggests you're fixing one error at a time rather then building a fundamental understanding of the tools you use.

So it's worth reading how Gradle does dependency management for you:

https://docs.gradle.org/5.3.1/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management

A minimal example can be found in the skeleton project. It is not tailored to your needs, but it should be a good starting point.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton

```kotlin
plugins {
    java
}
dependencies {
    testImplementation(platform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.0"))
    testImplementation(platform("io.cucumber:cucumber-bom:7.6.0"))

    testImplementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-java")
    testImplementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-junit-platform-engine")
    testImplementation("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    // Work around. Gradle does not include enough information to disambiguate
    // between different examples and scenarios.
    systemProperty("cucumber.junit-platform.naming-strategy", "long")
}
```